# Is It right conditional sentences OR I should use mixed structures?

Tags: conditional-constructions

second conditional

> 1) If I **were** more attentive I would **get** a better mark now *(first part- yesterday; second- current time)*

third conditional

> 2) If I **had been** more attentive I would **have had** a better mark yesterday *(first part- yesterday; second- yesterday)*

mixed e.g.

> 3) If I **had been** more attentive I would **get** a better mark now *(first part- yesterday; second- current time)*

Thank you

Comment: You can't do #3.  I am a native speaker, but I don't know how to explain why.  You can say *"If I **had been** more attentive I would **have** a better mark now."*, but you can't mix the way you did. Sorry I don't have a more coherent explanation for you!

Comment: @Choirbean Thanks. As far as I understand: _with the third one the only problem is the word 'get';_ 

I should use 'have' instead of 'get'. Is it right or you mistyped some words?

Comment: @Choirbean I did it _(used 'get' instead of 'have')_ in order to distinguish auxiliary verb (have) from the main verb (have)

Comment: Yes, you should have used "have", or if you wanted "get", you would say "be getting".  *If I had been more attentive, I would be getting a better mark now."

Comment: More context, please.

Comment: @userr2684291 What kind of context did you ask about? Certain action or state and certain day? You want to know his thoughts about probable outcome or dish for a supper. I don't follow you, sorry

Comment: Are you saying the whole context is enclosed in the parentheses? How would I know which sentence is *right* if I don't know the rest of the context? All of them are grammatical if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question because the issues with your sentences are subtle and hard to articulate. TL;DR your examples are indeed slightly odd, but not because of the time itself.

---

The subjunctive past can indeed be completed with reference to the present:

> If I were braver (in general), I would be standing on that bridge right now.

The pluperfect can, too:

> If I had been braver (when I made some particular choice that affects my present situation), I would be standing on that bridge right now.

The pluperfect can also be completed with reference to the past:

> If I had been braver, I would have been standing on that bridge yesterday.

---

The slight oddity in sentences (1) and (3), I believe, is the lack of a progressive element. In each of the above examples, I used either the conditional progressive or the conditional past progressive. That said, this seems to be a semantic requirement, not a grammatical requirement.

This also explains @Ben I.'s feeling about "I would get a better mark", with which I fully agree. To "get a mark" is a one-time event. Hence, you can either say you "would be getting a better mark" or "would get better marks", both of which stretch that action out over a period of time.

Similarly, a verb that implies a period of time is perfectly okay in simple present:

> If I were more attractive, I would receive more compliments.

Why do these conditions appear to demand a period of time? I suspect it has to do with the ability to describe something happening in the present time. You can't say you "would get a better mark" at the same time that it's happening.

---

It's worth noting that both the subjunctive past and the pluperfect be completed with a conditional perfect (for the same reason, I think):

> If I were braver, I would have stood on that bridge yesterday.
>
> If I had been braver, I would have stood on that bridge yesterday.

The event is in the past and can be referred to with a perfective at the time of utterance.

Your second sentence is thus okay, except that in North American English, at least, one doesn't "have" an individual mark. Hence, this is fine:

> If I had been more attentive I would have gotten a better mark yesterday.

(You can "have" a grade in a course, but not a mark on an assignment or test.)

---

Again for the same reason, you can also make reference to a hypothetical event using the plain old conditional to complete these phrases.

> If it were sunny out, I would go to the beach. *(But it isn't, so I won't.)*
>
> If he were more honest, he would get my vote.

Answer (score 0):

I used to teach English as a second language.

#1 is grammatically correct but not standard usage. You can refer to the present but most people would say, "If I were more attentive I would get better marks". The subjunctive "were" makes it a more general statement than just the particular mark in question.

#2 is correct and more standard, the time references agree.

#3 is incorrect, the tenses are inconsistent.